# Many-to-many (doubly-nested for-loop) in terraform

Tags: terraform

If I have 1 AWS resource A and multiple resources B, I can do something like:

```
resource "aws_something" "foo" {
  count = "${length(aws_something.B)}"

  field1 = "${aws_something.A.id}" 
  field2 = "${aws_something.B.*.id[count.index]}"
}
```

This gets me: "for every B, link A and that B in some way"

What if I now have multiple `A`s as well? What I'm looking for is: "for every A, for every B, link that A and B in some way" Conceptually this is like a doubly-nested for-loop.

Is there a way to set up this kind of many-to-many relationship in terraform?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out with the help of [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/833810/terraform-use-nested-loops-with-count).

Additional reading: [template_file documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html), [example](http://blog.aurynn.com/2017/2/26-more-fun-with-terraform-templates).